# SSL for security - Percona MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, ssl, percona-server

I have been told to implement SSL in my Master-Master MySQL instances by my security team to have secure traffic only to be received at the database end. I have never implemented SSL in a database instance and I have seen it only in App and Web layer.

Version - Percona 5.6 | Platform - Linux x86

I need to know are there any challenges in implementing SSL in MySQL and challenges if any, in regard to the application connectivity to the MySQL instance if SSL is implemented.

Also, when SSL is implemented, all the users (including the user which I use for Master and Slave) when created in the database should contain the keyword **REQUIRE SSL**  as given in [this link](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/06/22/setting-up-mysql-ssl-and-secure-connections/) including those application users which connects from the app to DB?

I'm thinking of referring steps mentioned in [How to enable SSL for MySQL server and client](http://xmodulo.com/enable-ssl-mysql-server-client.html)